# Non malleable Encryption scheme

Tags: encryption, one-time-pad, malleability

I know that one time pad is malleable. Can you give me an example of an encryption scheme which is non-malleable?

Comment: This is the reason why we always (??) use authenticated encryption :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO the best option to mitigate the maleability is using the authenticated encryption. So every scheme that includes the authentication tag should not be malleable (when done properly). Examples - the [GCM mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois/Counter_Mode), CCM, etc..

Comment: Just a consideration - the authenticated encryption is used to prevent malleabiity. Therefore using any resonable mode and attaching the a MAC tag will make the schema not maleable. (oh, use only well-known modes, I've seen ways to corrupt the MAC if not done properly)